# Transform of image downloaded from GEE is different when reading on QGIS or using Rasterio

Tags: qgis, google-earth-engine, rasterio, affine-transformation

I have downloaded Sentinel-2 image using GEE platform.

When I opened the image using QGIS, I was happy with the image as it seems to be right placed, With the following transform equation :

[image]

*False color representation

But when I open the image with rasterio, it was "flipped" :

```
img=rasterio.read('my_images/img.tif')
plt.imshow(img.read()[0,:,:]):
```

[image]

In order to check it, I have compared the transform of this image to transform of image of another sensor that is not flipped using rasterio .

```
#flipped image
flipped_img.profile['transform']
 >>>Affine(7.2135412378e-05, 0.0, 108.213452126442,
       0.0, 7.2135412378e-05, -0.2000110457149081)

#image that is not flipped by rasterio
not_flipped['transform']
>>>Affine(7.2135412378e-05, 0.0, 108.213452126442,
       0.0, -7.2135412378e-05, -0.2000110457149081)
>>>
```

As you can see, the only difference in the affine seems to be that the the 5th coordinate is "-" while in the flipped one is without - .

More information about the images downloaded :
-I have download more images with the same script (downloading from GEE) and not all of them are flipped, only few , which makes it more mysterious,

I have never encountered this issue, and it's very weird that on QGIS it reads the image correct without flipping it.
My question is what can cause this issue? how can I solve it?

Edit:
I have download again with the same script the same image. This time it was correct and wasn't flipped. no clue about what could make it happen.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be hitting a bug that occurred when relying on default projections.

It has since been fixed

Comment: Hi! thank you for your answer. Is this fixed on GEE cloud backend or in one of the client side (geemap/ee) libraries?

Comment: On the backend.

Comment: we are still experience this issue, can you please elaborate how can we avoid it? I have set the projection when saving image